# Revert github repository

Tags: git, github

I git push folder into a wrong repository. There are several files in this repository before I git push it. 
My previous files in this repository are gone after I git push a folder to this repository. I have reverted the folder by `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git push --force` , but not revert repository. 
 

 
Does anyone know how to get my previous file in this repository back ?

Comment: well you basically destroyed the upstream and your local repo. Use the reflog to see where you wrongly added the directory and do a reset again and a push force again. Hopefully you didn't shared the repo with others. If so, some heads will roll today.

Comment: Do you have, in the history of `other_repo`, the state of the folder before you force pushed it ?

Comment: Hi @ckruczek, finally  I solved my problem from support@github.com. I am still thank you for your  suggestion.

Comment: @LeGEC, I don't have the history of other_repo because I edited it on github, not on local repository. Finally I get all log I made on github from support@github.com, and get my all files back.

Comment: ok. Just for reference : you can see all the copies you ever had on your own local drive for a remote branch using : `git reflog <remote_name>/<branch_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Reset/undo the last commit then force push Or, revert the commit the push to repo.

```
# undo the last commit
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
$ git push -f

# revert the last commit (safe)
$ git revert HEAD~1..HEAD       # revert the last commit with new commit
$ git push
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.